# How do I remove the "ignore limit for today" option?

Tags: iphone, settings, screen-time, control-center

I have Screen Time set up on an iPhone. I scheduled downtime to always run, but it gives me three options:

- Ignore limit for 1 minute
- Ignore limit for 15 minutes
- Ignore limit for the rest of the day

I am fine with the first two options, but I'd rather exclude the third option.

Is it possible to get rid of the third option?

Comment: I don't believe Apple allows users to do that.

Comment: There’s no preference for this to configure so it’s highly unlikely these options can be customized/modified.